# How to use variable in path to another script?

Tags: powershell

Inside an existing PowerShell script I can call another script with a parameter like this:

```
.\Folder\Script.ps1 -parameter $data
```

But how do I use another variable for the folder part it self? The following part is not working:

```
.\$folder\Script.ps1 -parameter $data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Invoke-Command Cmdlet like this:

```
$command = ".\$folder\Script.ps1 -parameter $data"
Invoke-Command $command
```

Comment: I recommend you to escape `$data` in your string, so it is not expanded: ``$command = ".\$folder\Script.ps1 -parameter `$data"``. Currently, you just expand `$data` to its value. This can produce wrong command like so: `.\Folder\Script.ps1 -parameter Value with spaces`. And it will not work at all if `$data` is not a string, but some complex object. You should retain reference to variable instead expanding it to its value. It also will fail if `$folder` contains spaces, so you better [just use invoke operator `&`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33416409).